# What am I doing wrong with this web scraper?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am not getting any output file currently, I set up this script to scrape social profiles from the web when provided a list of emails. The  code is producing no output and I would like to learn what is wrong. I used ChatGPT to assist me in starting this project as  I am not a programmer by nature.

Here is the code:

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_social_profiles(email_list):
    social_profiles = {}

    for email in email_list:
        url = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={email}"
        headers = {
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3"}

        try:
            response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

            profiles = []
            for link in soup.find_all("a"):
                href = link.get("href")
                if href:
                    if "linkedin.com/in/" in href:
                        profiles.append({"platform": "LinkedIn", "url": href})
                    elif "instagram.com/" in href:
                        profiles.append({"platform": "Instagram", "url": href})
                    elif "twitter.com/" in href:
                        profiles.append({"platform": "Twitter", "url": href})
                    elif "facebook.com/" in href:
                        profiles.append({"platform": "Facebook", "url": href})

            social_profiles[email] = profiles

        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            print(f"Error: {e}")
            social_profiles[email] = []

    return social_profiles

    if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Read emails from "emailList.csv" file
        email_list = []
    with open("emailList.csv", newline="") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            email_list.append(row["Email"])

    social_profiles = get_social_profiles(email_list)

    # Save the social profiles information to a new CSV file
    with open("social_profiles_output.csv", "w", newline="") as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ["Email", "Platform", "URL"]
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()

        for email, profiles in social_profiles.items():
            for profile in profiles:
                writer.writerow({"Email": email, "Platform": profile["platform"], "URL": profile["url"]})

    print("Social profiles saved to social_profiles_output.csv.")
```

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Why do you have `if __name__ == "__main__":` inside the function? That's usually done at top-level of a script, to hold code that runs when you run the script instead of importing it. Did you copy the indentation wrong when you posted the question?

Comment: Where is the code that uses BeautifulSoup?

Comment: I have no idea what I am doing lol

Comment: We can't help you fix code that you don't show. There's no web scraper in the question.

Comment: What does "the previous code" refer to?

Comment: I was using ChatGPT to help start this project because I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Your indentation is still wrong. Is this how it is in the real script, or a copying error?

Comment: How it is in the real script

Answer (score 0):

The function should end at `return social_profiles`. Everything after that should be dedented. As a result, it's never calling the function, because the initial call is inside the function.

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_social_profiles(email_list):
    social_profiles = {}

    for email in email_list:
        url = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={email}"
        headers = {
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3"}

        try:
            response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

            profiles = []
            for link in soup.find_all("a"):
                href = link.get("href")
                if href:
                    if "linkedin.com/in/" in href:
                        profiles.append({"platform": "LinkedIn", "url": href})
                    elif "instagram.com/" in href:
                        profiles.append({"platform": "Instagram", "url": href})
                    elif "twitter.com/" in href:
                        profiles.append({"platform": "Twitter", "url": href})
                    elif "facebook.com/" in href:
                        profiles.append({"platform": "Facebook", "url": href})

            social_profiles[email] = profiles

        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            print(f"Error: {e}")
            social_profiles[email] = []

    return social_profiles

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Read emails from "emailList.csv" file
    with open("emailList.csv", newline="") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        email_list = [row["Email"] for row in reader]

    social_profiles = get_social_profiles(email_list)

    # Save the social profiles information to a new CSV file
    with open("social_profiles_output.csv", "w", newline="") as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ["Email", "Platform", "URL"]
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()

        for email, profiles in social_profiles.items():
            for profile in profiles:
                writer.writerow({"Email": email, "Platform": profile["platform"], "URL": profile["url"]})

    print("Social profiles saved to social_profiles_output.csv.")
```